# Defaulting system properties from a config file using maven

Tags: java, maven, properties-file

I have some system properties I specify from the command line
e.g.

```
mvn -Djdbc.url=... -Djdbc.user=... -Djdbc.password=... clean install
```

Instead of explicitly specifying each one from the command line I'd like to have a hardcoded `.properties` file that defaults these values but I can still override them with the command line as needed.

I know the `properties-maven-plugin` is one of several ways to read properties from a file, but how do I read properties and have them applied system wide? The properties seem to only work when used inside my `pom.xml`. If I have some other confg file (example a Hibernate config file), it doesn't seem to work.

Example:

In my `pom.xml` I have

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <!-- 
                            Alternatively this can read properties from a config file too 
                            Hardcoded inline here for example purposes
                        -->
                        <property>
                            <jdbc.url>...</jdbc.url>
                            <jdbc.user>...</jdbc.user>
                            <jdbc.property>...</jdbc.property>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Now I can use the `jdbc.*` properties anywhere in `pom.xml` and even override them from the command line as needed.

But in my Hibernate config file I have

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

        <property name="connection.url">${jdbc.url}</property>
        ...
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The `jdbc.url` and other properties show up as blank/null strings here because the properties I read from file only apply in my `pom.xml`. However if I specify it from the command line it works here since that applies application-wide.

Is there a good way to read properties and have them applied as they would be from the command line, application-wide?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using springboot?

Comment: @tryingToLearn - I am not, I'm using spark-java. Should have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up things;
the property you are referring to is inside the `properties-maven-plugin`, and you are configuring it so it can read the property for file.

But this is not the way to use "shared" properties inside maven, it's just a way to read some value from a file.

For being visible outside pom, you have to specify a property as a "global", in example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>*********</groupId>
<artifactId>******</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>*****</version>
<name>****</name>

<properties>
    <!-- Hibernate Configuration-->
    <jdbc.url>...</jdbc.url>
    <jdbc.user>...</jdbc.user>
    <jdbc.property>...</jdbc.property>
</properties>
```

Then, you can use these values into your hibernate conf:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect</property>

        <property name="connection.url">${jdbc.url}</property>
        ...
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

That way of setting global properties into the pom is the only way to let them visible outside of it.

I suggest you to move your hibernate connection info inside your pom, and eventually create more profiles, so you can edit them when building the corrisponding package.

Comment: Thanks @Leviland! That solution works well, although I'm struggling with 2 pain points. Firstly as the list of properties grows, that section becomes disorganized. It's a cosmetic problem of course, but would be convenient to have them in a file. Secondly it would be more organized to have different properties files for different tiers (local, dev, production, etc...). I know you mentioned maven profiles but I feel like they only go so far and still leave your pom cluttered. Appreciate the answer, just wondering if there's any other way at all that props could be global but remain in files

Comment: as far as I know, there's not a way to do what you wanna do. Btw profiles are still a good solution imho, they are good enough to keep things organized and readable! Glad have helped :)